# Find all C++ classes which use or inherit a certain class

Tags: c++, inheritance, llvm

I am working on a pretty big C++ code base and my task is to find all classes which inherit a specific class or have a member of that class type (QWidget in my case). I think one of the options might be using a llvm checker but I'm not yet sure how to do it. Any suggestions might be helpful.

Comment: Writing a `clang tidy` check that finds such classes seems like a reasonable option to me.

Comment: Without an external tool, aka determine it from inside the program or at runtime, I believe this is impossible, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: This task I mainly the reason why I use Resharper C++.